# Necessary and sufficient conditions for the vector of various pairwise distances in a graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Suppose that $n$ is a natural number. What's the necessary and sufficient condition on $(D_1,D_2,\ldots,D_{n-1})$ for there to exist a connected graph of size $n$ such that for every $i$, $D_i$ is equal to the number of pairs of nodes that are within a distance of $i$ to each other?

(Please note that distance here refers to the length of the shortest path between two nodes.)

Obviously, when the size of a graph is $n$, the diameter is at most $n-1$. So $D_k= 0$ for all $k>n-1$. Also, we know that the sum of all $D_i$ must be equal to $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.